# How to Apply a function to every 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 signals stored in pandas dataframe. The values of each signal are stored in 1 column at a time (Consequently, my dataframe shape `1,000,000 rows x 5 columns`). I would like to calculate the correlation between each and every signal in the dataframe. Therefore, my function takes 2 signals, that is, 2 columns at a time. Is there an easy and fast way to do that in pandas? **"Other than iterating over the columns explicitly"**

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: For loop with columns list

Comment: `df.corr()`....

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang for your answer, but what if I have another custom function? In my case, I am interested in calculating the concordance correlation coefficient CCC. How can we do that? Thank you

Comment: Either do a double for loop as Ben said, which is only `25`. Or write your function using broadcasting, similar to scipy's distance function.

Comment: @QuangHoang, How to write the function using broadcasting? I guess this is what I am looking for because I could have 1000s of signals.